My Primary Google Email Address Has been Taken Over
My primary Google email address has been hacked. Someone, somehow, added an email address to my Google account. I was quick enough to access my account and remove it. My problem now is, that I now no longer have access to my primary email, which is a Gmail account. There seems to be no way I can change this. I have always used 2 step verification, so unsure how they got access. I also have my Youtube account linked so cannot change this either. Any help/suggestions please

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. As troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic on this site, this question is not a good fit. Make it more focused and straightforward to make it a good fit. You are saying that the Gmail service was removed from your Google account. If that is correct only Google support can help with getting it back. Please follow the directions from the official help article for this: How to recover your Google Account or Gmail

Each Gmail address is effectively a Google Account.  You can add a recovery email address to another account (email).  So it is confusing as to what is being said.
There are many links from Google to help
From support

How to recover your Google Account or Gmail
If you forgot your password or username, or you can’t get verification codes, follow these steps to recover your Google Account. That way, you can use services like Gmail, Photos, and Google Play.
..
Forgot your password
..
Forgot the email address you use to sign in
..
Someone else is using your account
..
Can’t sign in for another reason
..
Recover a deleted Google Account

Try all the above steps.
Make sure you try this too

Secure a hacked or compromised Google Account
If you notice unfamiliar activity on your Google Account, Gmail, or other Google products, someone else might be using it without your permission. If you think your Google Account or Gmail have been hacked, follow the steps below to help spot suspicious activity, get back into your account, and make it more secure.
..

I have not copied all the information here as it will make the answer very verbose.
Besides, the information is likely to get updated regularly.
